# How can I correctly enable the orders creation from the Sylius Administration Dashboard?

Tags: sylius

I want to use the sylius default model and create orders from the admin dashboard, by default I just can edit orders created from the frontend but after having enabled the orders creation form, the items collection form:

`{{ form_widget(form.product, { "attr": { "class": "select2" } }) }}`

does not work.

Should I do something else?

Comment: So what's the error? (if there is one shown).

Comment: @AdamElsodaney Hi, I did not get any error, I just used the default project (sylius-standard), but I activated the Orders form in the admin, and the products selection does not work through the form, any of the products I created is displayed through this form, so I cannot associate one of them in the new order I want to create, e.g. take a look at the picture: [Sylius Create Order](http://f.cl.ly/items/2g0h3M3x3T461R1j3d1h/sylius_create_order.png)

Comment: Ahh I get it. If I have time, I'll write up a proper answer, but if you want to know where to get started, extend the [OrderType class](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Form/Type/OrderType.php#L23), then add to the builder `->add('products', 'collection', ...)` (search on GitHub for existing implementations), then [configure your new form type class](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml#L178)

Comment: Yeah, I should work however it doesn't! In fact my form ```OrderType``` extends to the  base ```OrderType``` like in the ```SyliusCoreBundle``` but it does not work. It's strange!